# How to create a multi line chart with with dynamic x and y axis in one graph using chart js?

Tags: javascript, charts

I want to create a multi line chart with dynamically changing values of x and y axis.Value for my Y axis are

```
traverse1 = [10,20,30,45,65,98]
traverse2 = [10,36,56,44,60,100]
traverse3 = [55,65,90,49,55,13]
traverse4 = [59,68,95,59,35,15]
```

Values for my X axis are

```
 master = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.5,,0.6]
```

All the values of X and Y will change dynamically by user.
I have tried to plot a graph but after changing the value dynamically my graph looks something like this grah. [image: My graph].

As you can see in the graph that for each line there is a seperate labels for X axis. What I want is common x axis for all the lines in the graph. Below Is the code that I have used to plot the graph.

```
function chartCall(master, traverse1, traverse2, traverse3, traverse4)
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById("barChart");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // Global Options:
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = 'black';
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 16;

    var dataFirst = {
            label: "Traverse 1",
            data: traverse1,
            borderColor: "rgb(151,187,205)",
          };

        var dataSecond = {
            label: "Traverse 2",    
            data: traverse2,
            borderColor: "rgb(220,220,220)",
          };

        var dataThird = {
                label: "Traverse 3",
                data: traverse3,
                borderColor: "rgb(247,70,74)",

              };

        var dataFourth = {
                label: "Traverse 4",
                data: traverse4,
                borderColor: "rgb(70,191,189)",
              };

        var speedData = {
                  labels: master,
                  datasets: [dataFirst,dataSecond,dataThird,dataFourth]
                };

    // Chart declaration:
    var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: speedData,
      options: {}
    });
}
```

Comment: the chart draws fine with the code above, how is it being changed?

Comment: On change of the input values, I call the same function with new values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the chart seems to draw fine with the code posted in the question,
even after changing the values and calling again.

see following working snippet,
click the button to update the chart with different values...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var traverse1 = [10,20,30,45,65,98];
  var traverse2 = [10,36,56,44,60,100];
  var traverse3 = [55,65,90,49,55,13];
  var traverse4 = [59,68,95,59,35,15];
  var master = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.5,,0.6];

  chartCall(master, traverse1, traverse2, traverse3, traverse4);

  document.getElementById('update').addEventListener('click', function () {
    var traverse1 = getRandomValues(6);
    var traverse2 = getRandomValues(6);
    var traverse3 = getRandomValues(6);
    var traverse4 = getRandomValues(6);
    var master = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.5,,0.6];
    chartCall(master, traverse1, traverse2, traverse3, traverse4);
  });

  function chartCall(master, traverse1, traverse2, traverse3, traverse4) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("barChart");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // Global Options:
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = 'black';
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 16;

    var dataFirst = {
      label: "Traverse 1",
      data: traverse1,
      borderColor: "rgb(151,187,205)",
    };

    var dataSecond = {
      label: "Traverse 2",
      data: traverse2,
      borderColor: "rgb(220,220,220)",
    };

    var dataThird = {
      label: "Traverse 3",
      data: traverse3,
      borderColor: "rgb(247,70,74)",
    };

    var dataFourth = {
      label: "Traverse 4",
      data: traverse4,
      borderColor: "rgb(70,191,189)",
    };

    var speedData = {
      labels: master,
      datasets: [dataFirst,dataSecond,dataThird,dataFourth]
    };

    // Chart declaration:
    var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: speedData,
      options: {}
    });
  }

  function getRandomValues(length) {
    var values = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      values.push(Math.random() * 10);
    }
    return values;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<input id="update" type="button" value="Update Chart" />
<canvas id="barChart"></canvas>
```